# dnf history undo last - Cannot find rpm nevra

Tags: dnf, alma-linux

I have done an update on AlmaLinux 8.6 to AlmaLinux 8.7. I would like to undo the update but it is not letting me. Here's the error message:

```
Error: The following problems occurred while running a transaction:
Cannot find rpm nevra "NetworkManager-1:1.36.0-9.el8_6.x86_64".
Cannot find rpm nevra "NetworkManager-adsl-1:1.36.0-9.el8_6.x86_64".
Cannot find rpm nevra "NetworkManager-bluetooth-1:1.36.0-9.el8_6.x86_64".
```

A simple way of undo would really be nice. Is there a way of backup a state of machine in order to revert easily should something go wrong?

Comment: Manage to undo by making a copy of almalinux.repo and replacing all the $releasever with 8.6.

Comment: btrfs snapshots

Comment: Filesystem is xfs so it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The following allows you to revert changes (Appstream packages) when upgrading from AlmaLinux 8.7 to AlmaLinux  8.8.

Copy the current configuration and make it the repository file for the previous AlmaLinux release.
`sudo cp /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-8.7.repo`

Replace all `$releasever` with the previous AlmaLinux version.
`sudo sed -i 's/$releasever/8.7/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-8.7.repo`

Update the value in the `[]` tag to the previous AlmaLinux version

```
sudo sed -i 's/\[baseos\]/\[baseos-8.7\]/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-8.7.repo
sudo sed -i 's/\[appstream\]/\[appstream-8.7\]/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-8.7.repo
sudo sed -i 's/\[extras\]/\[extras-8.7\]/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-8.7.repo
sudo sed -i 's/baseos-source\]/\[baseos-source-8.7\]/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-8.7.repo
sudo sed -i 's/\[appstream-source\]/\[appstream-source-8.7\]/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-8.7.repo
sudo sed -i 's/\[extras-source\]/\[extras-source-8.7\]/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-8.7.repo
sudo sed -i 's/\[baseos-debuginfo\]/\[baseos-debuginfo-8.7\]/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-8.7.repo
sudo sed -i 's/\[appstream-debuginfo\]/\[appstream-debuginfo-8.7\]/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-8.7.repo
sudo sed -i 's/\[extras-debuginfo\]/\[extras-debuginfo-8.7\]/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/almalinux-8.7.repo
```